# How to write select query comparing value in string (which contains array)

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I am using SQL Server. The select query returns me this:

[image]

`folder_name` field contains array. I need to check if it contains `s:1:"1"`. In other words, how can I get output like below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE [folder_name] like '%s:1:"1"%'
```